# How to merge two arrays without using inbuilt/predefined function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

Input arrays :

```
var arr1 = [{EmpID:'1',Name:'PB',EmpCode:'10001'},{EmpID:'2',Name:'SS',EmpCode:'10002'}]; 
var arr2 = [{EmpID:'1',Address:'GGN'},{EmpID:'2',Address:'SP-GGN'}];
```

Expected Output :

```
[{EmpID:'1',Name:'PB',EmpCode:'10001',Address:'GGN'},{EmpID:'2',Name:'SS',EmpCode:'10002',Address:'SP-GGN'}];
```

I tried below logic

```js
function fun(){
    var arr1 = [{EmpID:'1',Name:'PB',EmpCode:'10001'},{EmpID:'2',Name:'SS',EmpCode:'10002'}]; 
    var arr2 = [{EmpID:'1',Address:'GGN'},{EmpID:'2',Address:'SP-GGN'}];

    var arr3= [];
        for(var k=0; k < arr1.length; k++){    
        arr3.push(arr1[k]);
        }

    for(var k=0; k < arr2.length; k++){    
        arr3.push(arr2[k]);
        }
    console.log(arr3);

   
        var arr4 = [...arr1, ...arr2];
        console.log(arr4);
}

fun();
```

output result :

```
[{"EmpID": "2", "Name": "SS", "EmpCode": "10002"},{EmpID: '2', Name: 'SS', EmpCode: '10002'},{EmpID: '1', Address: 'GGN'},{EmpID: '2', Address: 'SP-GGN'}]
```

We can't use `array.filter()`, `.find()`, nested loop etc.., only customize logic is allowed.

Expected Output :

```
[{EmpID:'1',Name:'PB',EmpCode:'10001',Address:'GGN'},{EmpID:'2',Name:'SS',EmpCode:'10002',Address:'SP-GGN'}];
```

Comment: You can't do anything with arrays without built-in functions. `.push` is a built-in function.

Comment: are the arrays sorted by `EmpID`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two loops behind with an object for grouping instead nested loops.

This approach takes an object for grouping objects by `EmpID` and an array for the result set.

If you are allowed to use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), you could omit `result` and return only the values of `references`.

```js
function merge(a1, a2) {
    function add(array) {
        for (const object of array) {
            if (!references[object.EmpID]) {
                result.push(references[object.EmpID] = {});
            }
            for (const key in object) {
                references[object.EmpID][key] = object[key];
            }
        }
    }
    const
        references = {},
        result = [];

    add(a1);
    add(a2);
    return result;
}

const
    array1 = [{ EmpID: '1', Name: 'PB', EmpCode: '10001' }, { EmpID: '2', Name: 'SS', EmpCode: '10002' }],
    array2 = [{ EmpID: '1', Address: 'GGN' }, { EmpID: '2', Address: 'SP-GGN' }]
    result = merge(array1, array2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you can use a nested for loop to match the EmpID from both arrays. I think that should work:

```
function mergeArrays() {
  var arr1 = [{EmpID:'1',Name:'PB',EmpCode:'10001'},{EmpID:'2',Name:'SS',EmpCode:'10002'}]; 
  var arr2 = [{EmpID:'1',Address:'GGN'},{EmpID:'2',Address:'SP-GGN'}];
  var resultArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      if (arr1[i].EmpID === arr2[j].EmpID) {
        var mergedObj = {...arr1[i], ...arr2[j]};
        resultArr.push(mergedObj);
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(resultArr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arrow, but nested loop is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code, there are some minor mistakes in what you are doing, you need to put a second loop in the first loop, so that you can match the `EmpID` and then you in the object `Address` needs to be added according to the `EmpID` and then you need to push the object in the `arr3`, as you can see in the code below.

```js
function fun(){
    var arr1 = [{EmpID:'1',Name:'PB',EmpCode:'10001'},{EmpID:'2',Name:'SS',EmpCode:'10002'}]; 
    var arr2 = [{EmpID:'1',Address:'GGN'},{EmpID:'2',Address:'SP-GGN'}];

    var arr3= [];
    for(var k=0; k < arr1.length; k++){    
        let obj = {...arr1[k]}
        for(var j=0; j < arr2.length; j++){
            if (arr1[k].EmpID === arr2[j].EmpID) {
              obj = {...obj, "Address": arr2[j].Address}
            }
        }
        arr3.push(obj);
    }

    console.log(arr3);
}

fun();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = [{
  EmpID: '1',
  Name: 'PB',
  EmpCode: '10001'
}, {
  EmpID: '2',
  Name: 'SS',
  EmpCode: '10002'
}];

const arr2 = [{
  EmpID: '1',
  Address: 'GGN'
}, {
  EmpID: '2',
  Address: 'SP-GGN'
}];

const arr3 = arr1.map((arr) => {
  const x = arr2.filter((i) => arr.EmpID === i.EmpID)
  return { ...arr,
    ...x[0]
  }
})

console.log(arr3)
```

Comment: Thanks Schnd_ra, but inbuilt functions are not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

here my code

```js
const arr1 = [
  { EmpID: "1", Name: "PB", EmpCode: "10001" },
  { EmpID: "2", Name: "SS", EmpCode: "10002" },
];
const arr2 = [
  { EmpID: "1", Address: "GGN" },
  { EmpID: "2", Address: "SP-GGN" },
];

const arr3 = arr1.map((arr, index) => {
  const value = Object.values(arr1[index])[0];
  const indexArr2 = arr2.find((ar2) => ar2.EmpID === value);

  return (arr = { ...arr, ...indexArr2 });
});

console.log("arr3 :>> ", arr3);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).